# Any Ideas to get the image without noise

Tags: c#, image, camera, jpeg, ttl

Well im planning to do a project on automated water meter reading system. Where a camera will be fitted to the meter and captures the image to process and get the readings. Now when i fit the camera and capture the image , the image is with the noise due to shadows. Is there are any good ideas in order to detect the region of the numbers without the noise. I'll post the captured image for the reference and any ideas would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Please follow the link to view the image captured with noise http://www.electronicspoint.com/any-ideas-get-image-without-noise-t265023.html#post1583304

Comment: Is there any way to capture only the meter reading region?? Is there any kind of hardware to be added to achieve this?

Comment: What language are you using? Processing? Show us your code!

Comment: Im actually using C sharp emgu CV example to detect the numbers, but first i need to to detect the region of the numbers in the image which is inside a rounded rectangle. Would it be a better choice to detect the rounded rectangle or is it a better choice to do any kind of hardware changes?